# finding longest unique entry from list

Tags: python

I have a problem and can't seem to find a solution. I did regex on a free form text and it returns several results like below:
a = ['XY 621334', 'XY 621', 'XY 62133', 'AB 123', 'AB 1234']

my desired text is the longest unique values:
result = ['XY 621334', 'AB 1234']

can't figure out how to do this?

I've tried the below loop but it only works for the first type of combination 'XY ....'

```
long = ''
len_long = 0
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        if a[i] in a[j]:
            if len(a[j])>len_long:
                long = a[j]
                len_long = len(a[j])
        elif a[j] in a[i]:
            if len(a[i])>len_long:
                long = a[i]
                len_long = len(a[i])
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Could you add your definition of "longest unique entry"?

Comment: @OlvinRoght From the example, those entries that are not prefixes of other entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generator function producing the strings that are not prefixes of other strings in the list:

```
def unik(lst):
    lst.sort(reverse=True)
    pat = ""
    for s in lst:
        if not pat.startswith(s):
            yield s
        pat = s

list(unik(['XY 621334', 'XY 621', 'XY 62133', 'AB 123', 'AB 1234']))
# ['XY 621334', 'AB 1234']
```

The reverse sorting makes sure that all prefixes come right after their matches.

Comment: data is not defined

Comment: A minor typo - `for s in data` should be `for s in lst`?